# Will ailas be dropped in xterm after Linux login?

Tags: linux, terminal, tcsh, login-script

I'm using tcsh in red hat with a XFCE client. I want to make some setting in my .cshrc be execute only one time. I'm using the following command but it seems strange to me. The LOAD_SETTING env was reported as set when I start a xterm but the alias in the setting cannot be found. It seems my .cshrc was sourced at login time (I got the LOAD_SETTING environment variable set ) but some setting (at least alias) are not inherited. My question is which setting will be loaded and which will be lost in the terminal when I just start the terminal just after login?

I tried to change 'setenv LOAD_SETTING 3' to 'set LOAD_SETTING=3' and it seems works as expected: setting will be loaded when I start the terminal at first time but I just worried about the NOT environment variable is not safe enough as I'm trying to avoid SGE source my .cshrc for multi times.

```
if ! $?LOAD_SETTING then 
  echo "loading "`pwd`"/project_setting.csh"
  source /project/project_setup
  #force useful path order
  set path = (/tools/bin/x86_64/ /tools/cad/bin /sf/tools/cad/scripts /oge/sfgrid/6.2u5p1/wrapper /oge/sfgrid/6.2u5p1/bin/lx26-amd64 . /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /sf/tools/bin /sf/tools/cad/wrapper/bin $path)
  #delete repeated path
  set path=(`echo $path | perl -e 'print join(" ", grep { not $seen{$_}++ } split(/ /, scalar <>))'`)

  alias greg 'set ret=`find_tot` && $ret/bin/greg'
  setenv LOAD_SETTING 3
  exit 1
else
  echo "project_setting.csh has already been loaded, abort to load it again!"
  exit 1
endif
```

Comment: Environment variables are visible to new processes (such as a shell), while aliases are not.  So your test is not effective.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I will move the alias before the test condition so that it should work.